# .Net: Does dynamically loading an Assembly also load it's config?

Tags: reflection, .net-4.0

If in my project's execution/bin folder I have the following files:

```
MyDynamicLibrary.dll
MyDynamicLibrary.dll.config
```

and in my application I have this:

```
Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("MyDynamicLibrary");
```

if I invoke a method from this assembly object, will it have already loaded the information in the `MyDnamicLibrary.dll.config`?  If not, is there a way to load it so the dll functions correctly?  Or do I need to add the information in `MyDynamicLibrary.dll.config` to my application's .config file?

Comment: A dll.config is *never* considered by the CLR, it only looks at the .exe.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting a previous answer:

"[...] the configuration file being read is the configuration file of the hosting executable." (Hans is right on his previous comment)

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351604/problem-loading-assembly-via-reflection-and-accessing-configuration) question; you'll probably also want to take a look on [Microsoft's Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx).

Best,

Arthur